# docker-compose, node issue connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker-compose

I am trying to get node to connect to my local mysql from within docker-compose

I have verified node connects fine from the command line, and docker compose is loading node fine - I can access functions which don't use mysql via localhost

my docker compose file

```
       version: '3.6'
        
        services:
          mysql:
            container_name: mysql
            image: mysql:8.0.29
            ports:
              - "3306:3306"
            command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
            restart: always
            environment:
              MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
              MYSQL_USER: user
              MYSQL_PASSWORD: paass
              MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
              MYSQL_DATABASE: cine
            volumes:
              - './services/db/schema:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d'
        
          node:
            container_name: node
            build:
              context: ./services/node
              dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
            volumes:
              - './services/node:/usr/src/app'
              - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
            ports:
              - 3001:3001
            environment:
              - NODE_ENV=development
              - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
            depends_on:
              - mysql
        
          client:
            container_name: client
            labels:
              traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: 'true'
            build:
              context: ./services/client
              dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
            volumes:
              - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
              - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
            environment:
              - NODE_ENV=development
              - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
              - REACT_APP_API_URL=${REACT_APP_API_URL}
            depends_on:
              - node
        
          nginx:
            container_name: nginx
            build:
              context: ./services/nginx
              dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
            restart: always
            ports:
              - 3007:80
            depends_on:
              - node
              - client
```

and my node file

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const PORT = 3001;
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

require('dotenv-extended').load();

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'usser',
  password : 'pass!',
  database : 'cine',
  port     : '3306',
  socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
});


console.log('this works');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  res.json({ response: "hello!" });
});


app.get('/api/listfilms', function (req, res) {
sql="select * from films;";
  console.log(sql);
  connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results);
    results=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))
    console.log(results);
    if (results == ""){
        var response="error"; 
        var resp = [{
            "id": 0,
            "resp": response,
         },];
    }else{
    var resp = [{
           "id": results.id,
            "resp": results.name,
        },];
     }
     res.json(resp);
  })
})
```

the error i get is

```
node      | Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
node      |     at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
```

I have looked at other similar posts and tried their recommendations but none appear to work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your node config file the  host must be **mysql** not **localhost**. Since you have network configured in between containers, you just can use myql as the host of node config file